# How to 301 redirect a static url to another static url?

Tags: html, redirect, http-status-code-301

My website is HTML/CSS/JS website with no server (static website) sitting on MS Azure.
I have recently changed 2 of the html files like this:

www.mydomain.com/oldfile1.html

www.mydomain.com/oldfile2.html

To

www.mydomain.com/newfile1.html

www.mydomain.com/newfile2.html

how can I redirect the old url for the sake of SEO, considering the webiste is static and .htaccess doesn't work and it seems the using meta tag in html file is not considered as 301 permanent redirection?!

Answer (score 1):

A **301 Redirect** is a server side directive.

Anything you place in a client side file (`<meta>` / `javascript`)  cannot be read by the browser until the files arrive in the browser.

At this point it's *too late* to execute a server side directive.

You're now pointing the browser at the destination you're trying to point it away from.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Since `.htaccess` isn't working for you, you have two options: a) either introduce a server-side redirect via PHP (which can be a 301); or b) add a client-side redirect via `<meta http-equiv>` or javascript (which cannot be a 301).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best answer, but you could change the the html of oldfiles to redirect to the newfiles.

So something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Tells search engines to not index this page-->
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    <!--Redirect to new resource-->
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=www.mydomain.com/newfile1.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--In case both JavaScript and the meta tag fail-->
    <p>If you aren't automatically redirected please follow<a href="www.mydomain.com/newfile1.html">this link</a>.</p>
    <script>
       //JavaScript fallback if browser does not support/allow http-equiv="Refresh"
       window.location = 'www.mydomain.com/newfile1.html'
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: Correct, but it boils down to personal preferences.

Comment: It is not. There is no HTML specification showing any requirement for this. In fact, the standard specifically states that the slash has no meaning, it does nothing, and browsers are instructed to ignore it.

Comment: OP: _"[...] using meta tag in html file is not considered as 301 permanent redirection"_

Comment: Since his reason is for SEO, he could add the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` tag, which will result in _most_ search engines not indexing the page, just like _most_ search engines won't index 301 pages.